# How to wrap textbox around a shape?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've put some text in textboxes about a page and want them to fit around a circular image:

[image]

How can I configure the textboxes to have some sort of 'inner wrapping' mechanism so that I can make them fit around the image center page?

I'm using Microsoft Word 2013

Comment: You forgot to specify what program you are trying to do this in.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I'm using MS Word 2013